# Regex to find N digits among M characters

Tags: regex

What regex could be used to find a sequence in a text that contains at least N digits in a maximum M character length section?

It's for a simple general phone number (or other ID) text redaction. Detecting if there are at least 8 digits in a let's say 14 character length sequence of a text. (To account for the dashes, spaces, dots, whatever)

For example:
text: "Hi, my phone number is 6-432 / 2343.2"
match: "6-432 / 2343.2"

Comment: Maybe something like `(\d{1}[\d{1}\D?]{8,12}\d{1})` ?

Comment: `\d[\- /.\d]{7,13}`

Comment: Counting 9 digits in your *match*. How do you mean inside 14 characters of length, you meant from the first occuring digit to check the next 14 characters?

Comment: yes, any max 14 character sequence, starting with a digit, that contains at least 8 digits, and capture between the first and last digit in that match

Comment: this seems to be working: `/(\d(\d\D?){6,12}\d)/g`
edit: oh, maybe not... was a bit early to post

Comment: `/(\d(\d\D?){6,10}\d)/g` - finds any sequences from 8 to 22 length, with 8 to 12 digits in them, in the first capture group - if I see it correctly and my head hasn't blown up inside already